# how to change view controller using uisegmentcontroller in objective c

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to change view controller when segment is clicked. I am having `UITabBarItem` at the bottom so when I'll click on second or first segment, a view should change inside the current view controller.

When I used that code, the whole view overlapped from the current view, that's not what I want.

```
 if([sender selectedSegmentIndex] == 0) {
    //            UIStoryboard *mystoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    //            UITabBarController *wc = [mystoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@""];
    //            [self.navigationController pushViewController:wc animated:YES];
NSLog(@"first");
       } else if([sender selectedSegmentIndex] == 1) {
    //        UIStoryboard *mystoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    //        UITabBarController *wc = [mystoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProfileViewController"];
    //        [self.navigationController pushViewController:wc animated:YES];

 NSLog(@"Second");
   UIStoryboard *mystoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
   ProfileViewController *wc = [mystoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProfileFirstViewController"];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:wc animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need custom view controller container.
You can get good example here https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/custom-container-view-controller-transitions/